# Using AsyncTaskLoaders in Android makes UI bumpy

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask

I tried to implement doing some background calculation using an `AsyncTaskLoader`, just as I thought would be the right way to do it.
Calculation is done in a different thread, the UI can stay smooth and buttery.

But the opposite happend.

My UI has some sliding panels. The user swipes them open, selects something in there and while the sliding panel slides back into place, the background task is performing its calculations for the main display that is again revealed while the sliding panel moves back.

Now: when the background task is done and `AsyncTaskLoader.loadInBackground()` is finished, the `onLoadFinished` callback method of my fragment is triggered - it sets the adapter of the main contents to the new result and triggers `notifyDataSetChanged` of this adapter.

Whenever my background calculation is FAST, the sliding panel is not yet back in its retracted place and the update of the adapter's data makes the panel movement "hang"!

Thus: by using background tasks, I literally mess up my formerly smooth UI.

How do you guys deal with things like that??